# issue displaying two div's one after the other without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div's displayed one after the other.
I am displaying some data inside the div and don't want to show the div with scrollbar.
But with my below code, i can see the vertical scrollbar when the data is more. Any advice on how to show the entire div data with out scrollbar.

html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr style="height:5%">
            <td><h1>Title here</h1></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div .. />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div .. "/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: The code being output is significantly more than what you're displaying here and involves a slew of inline styles that affect the height.  I'm also confused why these items are placed in a `<table>` and why your above code is using duplicate ID values.

Comment: I have used <table> to keep two <div>'s one after the other inside <tr> tags. And the ID should be different it is some type error.@RobertC

Comment: Your usage of a table here at all seems unnecessary.  Why not just use `<div class="col-12" ng-controller="myController">...</div>`  You're basically mixing a CSS-derived layout with outdated table-as-grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

There's something important here, I don't know if it's causing you any trouble, but a div with class **row** should always be followed by another one (or multiple ones) with class **col-xx-n** in Bootstrap, where "xx" is the minimum screen size for displaying the columns and "n" is the amount of columns in which you wanna divide the **row**. Even if it's a single column: **class: "col-sm-12"**. This is important for a good responsive style.

Also, like @Robert said, change the id's to classes if they have the same value.

If you don't want a scroll bar to appear at all, you should try this in your css:

```
.timeline {
    scroll: none;
}
```

Hope it helped.